# running a parallel foreach where instead of a vector it uses columns on matrix

Tags: r, parallel.foreach

I'm trying to parallelize my function in order to run a simulation for a different set of parameters. One of the parameters of the function is a vector, so i'm trying to use each column of a matrix as the input vector of the function.
in this case the function works with a number of iterations so first i define a vector of iterations i want to test:

```
iterations<-c(2000,3000,4000)
```

then i define a matrix x.matrix:

```
xmatrix<-cbind(rep(0.2,5),rep(0.3,5))
       [,1] [,2]
  [1,]  0.2  0.3
  [2,]  0.2  0.3
  [3,]  0.2  0.3
  [4,]  0.2  0.3
  [5,]  0.2  0.3
```

i want My.function, which has vector x as one of the parameters, to run in parallel for each column of x.matrix acting as vector x as well as for each of the elements of the vector iterations

```
parallelize.my.function<-function(x.matrix,iterations){
  library(doParallel)
  registerDoParallel(cores=detectCores()-2)

   out.par<-foreach(i = iterations, .combine=rbind, .export= "My,function")%:%
           foreach(x = ... , .combine=rbind, .export="My.function") %dopar% {
  My.function(x, iterations)
}
```

i'm lost on what to type on the three dots to accomplish this.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn how to run foreach in parallel mode as a skeleton before adding in all your refinements.

First off, DON'T load libraries and/or do initialization stuff within a loop.  That is just about never good R programming and I have no earthly idea what starting multicore operations within a loop does, but I doubt it is useful and it sure isn't normal at the student level! Do this at the top.

Second, once you get a proper skeleton, then add components one at a time.

The recent doParallel package has truly simplified things (see documentation on CRAN) and pushes most of what has driven new students crazy for a long time under the hood. The following skeleton code shows how to access columns of a matrix in parallel fashion to get the same results as colSums(data)

```
library(doParallel)

set.seed(1L)
data <- matrix(sample(100,40,replace=TRUE),nrow=8)

registerDoParallel(cores=3)
foreach(i=1:ncol(data)) %dopar% sum(data[,i]) |> unlist() 
# unlist simplifies result to a vector here and the "|>" pipe operator is now 
# standard in the latest versions of R. If you have an older version, use:
# unlist(foreach(i=1:ncol(data)) %dopar% sum(data[,i])) 

colSums(data) # note gives same result as above
```

Obviously you wouldn't actually use the defined fn in this case as colSums() is highly optimized and many libraries now support parallel processing of vectors natively in any case.